# Linker error. MinGW can't export class from MSVS dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, mingw

I use MinGw (i686-4.9.2-win32) and trying to export the class from dll (which is made in visual studio)
But I get an error `undefined reference to _imp___ZN11ConsoleTestC1E'`

BUT function `foo()` from the same library exported without error..

Here my code

testdll.h

```
#ifdef CONSOLETEST_EXPORT
#define CONSOLETEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CONSOLETEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" class CONSOLETEST_API ConsoleTest{
public:
     ConsoleTest();
};
extern "C" void CONSOLETEST_API foo();
```

testdll.cpp

```
#include "testdll.h"
ConsoleTest::ConsoleTest(){}
void  foo(){}
```

And in main.cpp:

```
 #include "testdll.h"
 int main()
 {
  foo();
  ConsoleTest* cc = new ConsoleTest();
 }
```

PS: I tried to create a .a library from .dll :

```
pexports testdll.dll | sed "s/^_//" > testdll.def
dlltool -U -d testdll.def -l testdll.a
```

...but it did not help.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Just a note : since your using mingw, you don't have to mess with dllimport/dllexport. Mingw handles this automatically like on good ELF systems (if you get a linker warning, you can suppress it with the `-Wl,--enable-auto-import` option).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern "C" class` won't work.
You can dll-export a class, but not with C naming convention.

ISO C++03 7.5[dcl.link]/4:

> A C language linkage is ignored for the names of class members and the member function
>   type of class member functions.

If you remove the `extern "C"`, I see no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you! Oh, yes, you are right,  "c" and classes - I should have known..

No, without extern "C" even function "foo"  does not work.

In any case, I have not found a solution and have gone the other way.